# Adding multiple results form multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a SQL Server query to get the sum of the transaction amount and the pending amount and the extra amount. I found that the best solution to do that is using subqueries, hence I am using subqueries for the same, which is the fastest way. However, although I can extract the amount  from each subquery, I can't figure out how to add them together so I can sort by the total number.

Here's the current query:

```
 SELECT 
     *, trans + pend + extra AS totalamount
 FROM 
     (SELECT
          (SELECT trnammt
           FROM Tbl_Emi
           WHERE Status IN ('N', 'P')
             AND lastrecdate = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
             AND CardNo = CardNo) AS TRANS,
          (SELECT pendamt
           FROM Tbl_Emi
           WHERE Status IN ('N', 'P')
             AND lastrecdate = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
             AND CardNo = CardNo) AS PEND,
          (SELECT extraamt
           FROM Tbl_Emi
           WHERE Status IN ('N', 'P')
             AND lastrecdate = (SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi)
             AND CardNo = CardNo) AS EXTRA
    FROM 
        Tbl_Emi) q
```

I need to add together trans and pend and extra to get 'totalamount'. SQL Server won't allow you to use simple syntax to do calculations on aliases, but I presume there's another way to do this?

Comment: do you need trans,pend and extra seperately?

Comment: It doesnt matter, what mattet is that the result should be the sum of them

Comment: so why you need as subquery when all data  stored in one table
you can get them whit simple query

Comment: Because as you can see the last subquery is having a different condition, so it cannot be all spooled together

Comment: What's the actual error message you get from the code example in your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want sum of `trans + pend + extra` you need to change the criteria part

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN (lastrecdate = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                 AND CardNo = CardNo) THEN trnammt
             ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE WHEN (pendamt = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                 AND CardNo = CardNo) THEN trnammt
             ELSE 0
        END +
        CASE WHEN (lastrecdate = (SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi)
                 AND CardNo = CardNo) THEN trnammt
             ELSE 0
        END AS totalamount
  WHERE Status IN ('N','P')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three problems I can readily see:

- The subqueries are not aggregated, so if they return multiple rows, you will get an error.
- The correlation conditions only refer to the subquery (so they are not really correlated).
- The results could be `NULL`, so the sum would be `NULL`.

This version fixes these three problems:

```
 SELECT e.*,
        (COALESCE(trans, 0) + COALESCE(pend, 0) + COALESCE(extra, 0)) AS totalamount
   FROM (
         SELECT (
                 SELECT SUM(trnammt)
                   FROM Tbl_Emi e2
                  WHERE Status IN ('N','P')
                    AND lastrecdate = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                    AND e2.CardNo = e.CardNo
                ) AS trans,
                (
                 SELECT sum(pendamt)
                   FROM Tbl_Emi e2
                  WHERE Status IN ('N','P')
                    AND lastrecdate = (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
                    AND e2.CardNo = e.CardNo
                ) AS pend,
                (
                 SELECT sum(extraamt)
                   FROM Tbl_Emi e2
                  WHERE Status IN ('N','P')
                    AND lastrecdate = (SELECT MIN(lastrecdate) FROM Tbl_Emi)
                    AND e2.CardNo = e.CardNo
                ) AS extra
           FROM Tbl_Emi e 
        ) e
```